# Why does ArcMap 10 export circles instead of diamonds?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

### My default symbol for building is a small square.
A jpg export or any other export renders it as a small circle.
It's a killer for hydrology maps which use circles for many other items.  Solutions?

From the posts i went back and looked at the default symbols that the open-source layer provided.  It LOOKED like a square rotated.  But it was something else...yes a circle!
Not sure why this happens in Arc...However I simply changed my symbol and voila! it exported just fine.

While i got what i needed the probelm persists.  When i went back and looked at the square it said it was a polygon!  Odd.  Anyway thanks to these posts I now have a work around;

[image: compostite of parameters for default symbol]

Comment: Are you using the default symbology? Can you post a screen capture of the symbol in ArcMap and another one after it has been exported?  What export parameters are you using?

Comment: @Jakub - I think with a rep of 6 that won't be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the fact that you said that this problem occurs with JPG and other exporters suggests to me that this answer might not work for you, but give it a shot anyways as I have used this to solve similar issues with PDF exports.

For PDF exports, try setting the following options under the format tab:

[image: Image of export dialog Format tab for PDF exports in ArcMap 10.0]

- **Picture Symbol**: Vectorize layers with bitmap markers/fills
- **Convert Marker Symbols to Polygons**: Checked
- **Embed All Document Fonts**: Checked

**Note:** Setting all 3 options may be overkill so you can try one at a time.

Comment: Downvoter, I am sorry if you find the answer unhelpful but I am leaving it for reference.

Comment: probably the reason it was downvoted is we can't see what options you are talking about...

Comment: The image isn't showing up? Strange. I added a textual description of the settings.

Comment: I can see the image in IE8.

Comment: ok, I was on IE7, now on Chrome, and it's fine. Grrr work computers!!